# Show divs if selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a select box with options like: bar, restaurant, hotel. 
And from list with all objects if user choose eg. bar, objects with restaurant and hotel should be hidden.
Check my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s0w98owg/

The problem is, when i choose **bar** only 1st div is changing

js:

```
$('#type').change(function(){
if ($(this).val() == "bar") {
    $("#restaurant").hide();
    $("#bar").show();
} 
else if ($(this).val() == "restaurant") {
    $("#bar").hide();
    $("#restaurant").show();
} });
```

Comment: There is an error coming - Uncaught ReferenceError: filterMarkers is not defined

Comment: Looks like you have duplicate `id`s in the attached fiddle code. You can use `class` instead.

Comment: Perfect :) The problem was ID. restaurant, bar should be class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not give the same id to multiple objects. You can given the same id `bar` and `restaurant` to multiple tags.

Do this:

```js
$('#type').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "bar") {
        $(".restaurant").hide();
        $(".bar").show();
    } 
    else if ($(this).val() == "restaurant") {
        $(".bar").hide();
        $(".restaurant").show();
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type" onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">Wybierz kategorię</option>
    <option value="restaurant">pierwsza</option>
    <option value="bar">druga</option>
 </select>
<ul id="pasekBoczny">
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(0)">Jasło</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(1)">Jaworzno</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar bar"><a href="javascript:myclick(2)">Jędrzejów</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(3)">Solidarności</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar bar"><a href="javascript:myclick(4)">Łódź</a></li></ul>
```

I have changes id name into class and in JS I have given `.` instead of `#`.

You can also try below optimize JS:

```
$('#type').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $("#pasekBoczny li").hide();
    $("."+selected+"").show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Id be unique in html Instead of id Use common class for all li tag**

html be

```
<select id="type" onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">Wybierz kategorię</option>
    <option value="restaurant">pierwsza</option>
    <option value="bar">druga</option>
 </select>
<ul id="pasekBoczny">
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(0)">Jasło</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant" ><a href="javascript:myclick(1)">Jaworzno</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar bar" ><a href="javascript:myclick(2)">Jędrzejów</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant" id="restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(3)">Solidarności</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar bar" ><a href="javascript:myclick(4)">Łódź</a></li></ul>
```

**jquery code be simple**

```
$('#type').change(function(){
    $(".list-sidebar").hide(); // hide all the li haveing common class
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show(); // show the particular selected class
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s0w98owg/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Id should be unique use class instead of id ,then you can write a code in single line

**HTML**

```
<ul id="pasekBoczny">
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(0)">Jasło</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(1)">Jaworzno</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-sidebar bar"><a href="javascript:myclick(2)">Jędrzejów</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-sidebar restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(3)">Solidarności</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-sidebar bar"><a href="javascript:myclick(4)">Łódź</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('#type').change(function () {
    $(".list-sidebar").not("." + this.value).hide().end().filter("." + this.value).show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s0w98owg/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using from multi id with one name! Try chnage them to attribute:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siamakferdos/s0w98owg/6/)

```
<select id="type" onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">Wybierz kategorię</option>
    <option value="restaurant">pierwsza</option>
    <option value="bar">druga</option>
 </select>
<ul id="pasekBoczny">
    <li class="list-sidebar" data-li-id="restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(0)">Jasło</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar" data-li-id="restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(1)">Jaworzno</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar" data-li-id="bar"><a href="javascript:myclick(2)">Jędrzejów</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar" data-li-id="restaurant"><a href="javascript:myclick(3)">Solidarności</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar" data-li-id="bar"><a href="javascript:myclick(4)">Łódź</a></li>
</ul>

$('#type').change(function(){

    if ($(this).val() == "bar") {
        $("li[data-li-id='restaurant']").hide();
        $("li[data-li-id='bar']").show();
    } 
    else if ($(this).val() == "restaurant") {
        $("li[data-li-id='bar']").hide();
        $("li[data-li-id='restaurant']").show();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to show different list sections with different ID's

```js
$('#type').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "bar") {
        $("#restaurant").hide();
        $("#bar").show();
    } 
    else if ($(this).val() == "restaurant") {
        $("#bar").hide();
        $("#restaurant").show();
    } 
  else if($(this).val() == ""){
        $("#bar").show();
        $("#restaurant").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type" onclick="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">Wybierz kategorię</option>
    <option value="restaurant">pierwsza</option>
    <option value="bar">druga</option>
 </select>
<ul id="restaurant">
    <li class="list-sidebar" id=""><a href="javascript:myclick(0)">Jasło</a></li>
    <li class="list-sidebar" id=""><a href="javascript:myclick(1)">Jaworzno</a></li>
   
    <li class="list-sidebar" id=""><a href="javascript:myclick(3)">Solidarności</a></li>

</ul>
<ul id="bar">
     <li class="list-sidebar" id=""><a href="javascript:myclick(2)">Jędrzejów</a></li>

    <li class="list-sidebar" id=""><a href="javascript:myclick(4)">Łódź</a></li>    
</ul>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/s0w98owg/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I've included some HTML to confirm what you mean

```
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
    <option value="hotel">Hotel</option>
</select>
<div id="bar" class="type">Bar</div>
<div id="restaurant" class="type">Restaurant</div>
<div id="hotel" class="type">Hotel</div>
```

Now the jQuery

```
$('div.type').hide();
$('#type').change(function()
{
    $('div.type').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).toggle();
});
```